# How to determine method visibility based on the caller?

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering what the generally accepted pattern would be for providing methods with that require "privileged access" which only certain other object types might call.

For example, if you have a Bank object, with a collection of Accounts, you might want to let "Bank" call account.sendMoneyTo(...), but let a much broad set of objects call account.balance or account.name.

All the ways I can think of to do this seem clunky, the only approach that seems to make any kind of sense is to have multiple interfaces to the account object, one for privileged functions, and one for more "public" functions, but perhaps I'm missing something obvious,

Thanks.

Here's a simple implmentation to illustrate.  Let's say you have thing called a "MoneyBag", and the idea is that a "Person" can lend money or receive Money via a MoneyBag, but that they can't create Money.  Assume the only entity that can create money is a "Treasury",and you can borrow money from the Treasury.  That might look like the below.

The problem is how to deal with the mint function of the MoneyBag,
Ideally only the Treasury should be able to call it.  But since there is no "friend" function, nor is it possible to create an interface in front of the MoneyBag so that only Treasury sees the mint function (because static methods can't be included in interfaces), it seems I have to implement this function that requires the caller to identify themselves (via the "requestor" parameter.). This seems suboptimal to me.  Better if there were a mechanism where only "Treasury" could call call `mint` on a MoneyBag.

```
    interface PersonOrEntity {
    id : string
    isTreasury : boolean;
}
class Treasury implements PersonOrEntity {
    readonly  isTreasury : boolean = true;
    private loans : Map<string, number> = new Map();
    id : string;
    constructor(id : string) {this.id = id}
    requestLoan(amount : number, borrower : PersonOrEntity) : MoneyBag {
        this.loans.set(borrower.id, amount);
        return MoneyBag.mint(amount, this);
    }
}
class Person implements PersonOrEntity {
    readonly id: string;
    constructor(id: string) {this.id = id}
    readonly isTreasury = false;
    private bag : MoneyBag = new MoneyBag();
    get balance() : number {return this.bag.balance}
    addBag(newBag : MoneyBag) {
        this.bag.add(newBag)
    }
    lend(amount : number) : MoneyBag {
        if (amount > this.bag.balance) {
            throw new Error("insufficient funds");
        }
        let newBag = this.bag.split(amount);
        return newBag;
    }
}
class MoneyBag {
    private _balance: number = 0;
    constructor() {}
    get balance() : number {return this._balance}
    

    //Only Treasury instance can call?
    static mint(amount: number, requestor: PersonOrEntity): MoneyBag {
        if (requestor.isTreasury || amount == 0) {
            let bag = new MoneyBag()
            bag._balance = amount;
            return bag;
        }
        throw new Error("not authorized");
    }
     public add(bag : MoneyBag) {
        this._balance += bag.balance;
        bag._balance = 0;
    }   
     
    public split(amount: number): MoneyBag {
         if (this.balance < amount) {
            throw new Error("Insufficient funds");  
         }
         let newBag = new MoneyBag()
         newBag._balance = amount;
         this._balance -= amount;
         return newBag;
    }
}
 
let T = new Treasury("USA");
let steve = new Person("Steve");
let jane = new Person("Jane");
steve.addBag(T.requestLoan(100, steve));
jane.addBag(steve.lend(50));
console.log(steve.balance, jane.balance);
```

Comment: The only way I could see this happening is having the Bank extend Account and making it a protected method.

Comment: Seems like you're talking about `friend` classes as requested in [ms/TS#7692](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7692), but there's no direct support for that. Could you provide a [mre] we can paste into our IDEs so that we have something concrete to work with (instead of just a verbal description of it)?

Comment: Well, yes, friend would be great.  And static methods in interfaces would be great to which would help a lot with these kind of problems.  I put maybe an overlong example in the above which is a maybe half-assed way to handle the problem, but perhaps there is a better way.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't really look like a [mre] from my perspective; if I drop that into the TypeScript playground [like this](https://tsplay.dev/wgDM9N) I see a *lot* of errors presumably unrelated to your issue, and it's probably not a great idea for the example to be more than two hundred lines long; if an example can't fit on a single screen then either it's not a *minimal* example or the problem is possibly not a good fit for Stack Overflow.  Anyway if you could clear those up I'll come back and look.

Comment: ok, i will try again!

Comment: PS All the errors go away if you turn off strict null checks (I don't initialize all the variables up front) and set it to ES2020 (to allow bigint).  I've tested it and it compiles/ runs fine.  But I agree its too long.

Comment: If your code has errors with `--strict` then I’m probably not going to be too interested in dealing with it.  Maybe someone else will come along who is more familiar with and interested in code with unresolved null check errors.

Comment: The new version is strict.

Comment: The least clunky workaround I can envision is [this version](https://tsplay.dev/W4joON) where you make `mint` a `private` method and then work around that inside `Treasury`, along with whatever comments you need to discourage others from doing so.  Otherwise you have to start trying to build your encapsulation like [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaEK2N) and that starts getting ugly.  How do you want to proceed here? I could write up any of this as an answer, but I don't know if it's something you want to see.

Comment: Thanks, these examples are both great.  I was unaware you could end run a private modifier with the syntax  MoneyBag["mint"](amount);   I was also unaware of the Omit keyword, which is also very useful to know about.  Haven't much used namespaces, but here's maybe a good reason to.   I think both approaches would be useful for anybody facing a similar quandry.   Thanks so much!

Comment: Just to note that the if statement on line 42 and the throw on 47 have have to be deleted, or your first example won't run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without *`friend` classes* as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7692](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7692) there's no clean and ergonomic way to do this, unfortunately.

One easy but unclean workaround is to just use [a `private` method](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private) but to allow your intended friend class to ignore the request for privacy by indexing via [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation), as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#19335](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19335):

```
class MoneyBag {
  // ...
  private static mint(amount: number): MoneyBag {
    let bag = new MoneyBag()
    bag._balance = amount;
    return bag;
  }
}

class Treasury {
  // ... 
  requestLoan(amount: number, borrower: PersonOrEntity): MoneyBag {
    this.loans.set(borrower.id, amount);
    // explicitly work around private
    return MoneyBag["mint"](amount);
  }
}
```

Now, interlopers will still be warned against using that method:

```
MoneyBag.mint(10); // error!
// Property 'mint' is private and only accessible within class 'MoneyBag'.
```

Yes, of course, a nefarious individual could write `MoneyBag["mint"](10)` but  we're mostly just talking about a type system here and not some hardened known-secure-at-runtime system.  If you need something like that, you'd probably be best ignoring the type warnings and maybe classes altogether and just use scoping and closures to hide things.  But I digress.

---

You could take the approach of keeping your intended friends in a scope together and then exporting only those pieces you want to be accessible from the outside.  But this gets kind of ugly:

```
namespace Capsule {    
  export class Treasury {
    // ...
    requestLoan(amount: number, borrower: PersonOrEntity): MoneyBag {
        this.loans.set(borrower.id, amount);
        return _MoneyBag.mint(amount);
    }
  }    
  class _MoneyBag {
    // ...
    _balance: number = 0;
    get balance(): number { return this._balance }
    static mint(amount: number): MoneyBag {
      let bag = new _MoneyBag()
      bag._balance = amount;
      return bag;
    }
    public add(bag: MoneyBag) {
      if (!(bag instanceof _MoneyBag)) throw new Error("hey");
      this._balance += bag.balance;
      bag._balance = 0;
    }    
  }    
  export type MoneyBag = Omit<_MoneyBag, "_balance">;
  export const MoneyBag = _MoneyBag as 
    (new () => MoneyBag) & Omit<typeof _MoneyBag, "mint">    
}    
const Treasury = Capsule.Treasury;
type Treasury = Capsule.Treasury;
const MoneyBag = Capsule.MoneyBag;
type MoneyBag = Capsule.MoneyBag;
```

Here we've scoped the friends into a `Capsule` [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html), and are only exposing `Treasury` and `MoneyBag` class constructors and types, which don't contain the `mint` static method or the `_balance` instance property.  It's clunky, because you have to do a lot of redundant naming, even though [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) makes that a little less tedious... and because you have to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the `bag` passed to `add()` is actually from `_MoneyBag` inside the friend zone and not something that happens to have the same members as the exported `MoneyBag` type.

But it works:

```
MoneyBag.mint(10); // error!
// Property 'mint' does not exist on type
```

Again, this actually does do the bad thing at runtime; it's just a typing error to do this.  If you need [Fort Knox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fort_Knox), you should pay attention to runtime guarantees first and then add types later.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-tUkTcAiytGMhODRWwUpSqPhwERKLRWQrIxqyqrU2DciJpYcwEQUx+XR6aCOcoVCZx+lRZxH7cQ5oZUVEjdrVfLldRcZlQ7Ho5n43ny4ZZrIpmAogNRtw3b+aDhSorKrR4QKGGoSGPtKQ-Sx5xHcnXE4gK4KmOOMlBhGTggUjdUKG0ahqC5DAIEoJBqDFKB1RNf892EUxcGAqsBnfYdR1gYxeGfY1g1lIlB23JZd2sEhLQcKAnHra9cLvCVi1KAB9cdKkQM9ewGAAGYNQyqcNNm2OMpwKFtsN4jsIC7Doe0YftKLQRV8LOHiQB-GThCLEpkGkPAuSQLVKFI08VPPS8WKXW9Vyw0tq2Aq9HKmVdPx0hTJyyGlKHIpAB001zgwwmAtH0Yj4GFUQj0-Rcbz-f9tN0-SAGosh8vy8m80cMr45AshE2iGSimLzKIkjAps35e3shtUS9f8HyfbS8qQBphUNWlUv-E4gNrJBQOBbZ1QASSqLRoNg+DsKQw8ULQ01nNbaiBhGhyby8wbqN8vTioGOrgvSrqAFoAr6oLV1CxVqIiujFBclQtuGZwsyScZ1QAVQAZQAQVQmYXOkCAsBK9yIVYH7-vwSGQZe1sACtKihkaYbedUACl0aRshwchs4Z0bFQznuR5cBeSpxgARiEoT2iJ380LRisSYSxsWdxeCjwAViEyY0LElhTFxZg5HGHm8vadmIG-Yq0J2qszks4kGemJBmVZMC0AAQkUHX0GYGBGE9ABydWLfIJwjJLSpxRiAQEEQJiMBi5Ahl4U5FStJikAtlXUQts4SAtIhQEgWA6FGjt6m0BxSmIRRtUYWhJyxoIYTCBkAxjBR70zVwkgMIxTEqGYLTIKPoDgScAGEE60Ux0QZdkYC2bD-acBJs3tbwFpdAIoWCUJWu9KJndtvvS5Scv0iyHJ8sG+3SjxKpanqJoFnkdoGr6d663qJtV3z3eaMG0WJMjc+Wmk7Sk3IcUMIoh5oGp15rIE-557A8lwSulHjnJqrEWrsQAucDeBIiQki2GSRglJqQ3TpMFCi8owpcWDl+dW1lVrCAwtXYQPckBYOak5QaRVFI-z7KVYK180DrEklMI4r8kByTbMVZSB8+zxnumuKhk42GmRCHFXBdUaGgMchPf8LlPxH1Idgvag1XKHX0tdE8aCQoaUVJ+YKbDKqxXiolMsHkUoyPvI+cY+sSQtUgrgYqzBHxkLAXIYWQ0QTuTGuBY4iICYqPOkdRSSBsqqLylonygioZlUGkQgohjqqcmJBI2yjVkpsVXCIKxnUgmTh6nVAaATAKeJGt4ia00oIwW5AtRCyF-GxMyWUDawxcI1g+i4zykxGkHSiSdFBWjAn6Sur1TRjT+GPVXIQ2wwgO5d2yHwM2ZjWlIDYFqXADQOk3naOqKJ6pejBlmWgbuYYlktSyJs3CmgnwjRYRkfo2DDgADIVlrIaPwM2TjFHkO2erPZz0VjiU+iXdwWQm4wETgrWeugZjvOQFCnMSAwUQrOPCmY19TluSRS3BW2CYULOQNggYWLxa4umSQrGA9HRDxtCPbOHpc6T3THEaMF9RJhkYRGbYd8DhHEfuKZML9Uw+mnvEL6ILEJ6QLBVSUpQkoYoUUo-BHC8rcNUrw7RGCtLYnXF+LqGFSaoi3C00xDyLFrh8puaiXS1oFAPEeFJPCpE3jNe1ayr5zWjjyoUgCw0PplJ+pBWaVS4IISWqIFa+j1rYU2kvbVPkarJJQfg9BVFjWXwIc9ZG2E3ptJGPCn6ANgZoTBgjDGH0sZw1Lf4ly8sFEVtxvjNCPMDVS3JpTD+NM3gMyZvMCGrMZjy05rOQ1PM7XjEFsLNFqw0gSyljLXJEA5bo0VopZW5C1banpkLcw2sWSMHGobMgxtgRmyOQIK22obbRGgB0Zg2F2TKGwqweZZtw5AA)

Comment: V Helpful.  One other approach I was thinking about was to define a MoneyBag class in a module without exporting it, and have an exported Factory, Treasury and IMoneyBag interface in the same file, all exported.  The factory could return empty moneybags using the IMoneyBag interface which doesn't expose the mint function.   Does that make sense as sort of an approximation of "friend" scope?  Not Fort Knox obviously, but maybe good enough to make it clear that only Treasury can mint money?